# Converting milliseconds to timestamp in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, timespan, milliseconds

I get milliseconds from my datasource. This column is called `duration`.
The column `duration` is on the Y axis on my ssrs report. (bardiagram)

Now I want to format these milliseconds to hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds.

What I did:

```
=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Fields!Duration.Value)
```

But on my report I get only the hours/minutes on my Y axis

It would be awesome if you could help me.

Thank you

Comment: You can convet it into string  `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(...).ToString(@"hh\/mm\/ss\/fff")`gives you the result in format _hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds_

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried this `=TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Fields!Time.Value).ToString("hh\/mm\/ss\/fff")` but then I get only numbers from 0 to 10

I think it cant convert it...